# SQL | LIMIT Clause | limit not achieved

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

I have the following query to get iPhones from table1 by color and limited to 10

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE color = 'black' LIMIT 10
```

The above code works perfectly, When the black iPhones in table1 less than 10 I want to complete the iPhone's number to 10 with red color which I have also in table1 in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on both colors, and do a conditional sort:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE color in ('black', 'red')
ORDER BY color = 'red'
LIMIT 10
```

Condition `color = 'red'` yields `1` when fulfilled, else `0` - so this actually puts `'black'` first.

You can also use `field()` here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE color in ('black', 'red')
ORDER BY FIELD(color, 'black', 'red')
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks it's working..
I'm wondering if there is any other way to do the same work with if statement or something like that

Comment: @EmmaGrove: well, you could do `ORDER BY IF(color = 'black', 0, 1)'`... But the above expressions are simpler.